# Кавычки в <span>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Большие объемы текста в теге  помещаются в кавычки, маленькие нет, видимо в целях безопасности, так вот, можно ли как то обойти это ограничение и сделать так чтобы даже большие объемы текста вставлялись без кавычек?
Нужно мне это для того чтобы можно было при необходимости в этот текст встраивать другие теги, но из-за кавычек они не распознаются как теги, а как обычная строка. Теги должны встраиваться в любые места, поэтому заранее создать тег в каком-то конкретном месте я не могу.
Для создание страниц я использую jinja (использую шаблонизатор в самих html страницах) и flask.
Либо есть ли другие способы встроить тег посреди строки?

Comment: Не понятно, о каких кавычках идёт речь. Если хотите вывести html код (не экранируя теги), используйте фильтр `safe`: `{{ text|safe }}`

Comment: Ваш совет помог, хоть я и пробовал его раньше сам, но один лишний span в коде портил всю малину, убрал и все заработало, спасибо тем не менее!)